# xslt integrating an xsl when template

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, rdf

I have been working on the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <root>
  <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
       ....
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">

     ....
  <skos:Concept rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_26321">
       ....
   <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Abies mariesii</skos:prefLabel> 
   <skos:broader rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10"/>
  </skos:Concept>

  <skos:Concept rdf:about="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_5886">
          ....
   <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Pinaceae</skos:prefLabel>
   <skos:narrower rdf:resource="http://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_10"/>
  </skos:Concept>

  <skos:Concept>
   <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="ar">شوح</skos:prefLabel>
   <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="fa">آبیس</skos:prefLabel>
              ......
   <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="es">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
   <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="en">Abies</skos:prefLabel>
   <skos:closeMatch>
       ....
 </rdf:RDF>
 </root>
```

I am able to get the value of narrower skosprefLabel xml:lang=en and broader skosprefLabel xml:lang=en with the following templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
       ......
 xmlns:void="http://rdfs.org/ns/void#">
 <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

 <xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:for-each select="rdf:RDF">
  <xsl:text>START HERE</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
    .....
  <xsl:apply-templates select="skos:Concept" />
  <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
    ....
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="skos:Concept">
   <xsl:for-each select="skos:prefLabel|skos:Concept" />
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="skos:broader">
     <xsl:text>=301  \\$abroader$b</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="skos:prefLabel[@xml:lang='en']" />
     <xsl:text>$c</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="./@rdf:about" />
     <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="skos:narrower">
     <xsl:text>=302  \\$anarrower$b</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="skos:prefLabel[@xml:lang='en']" />
     <xsl:text>$c</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="./@rdf:about" />
     <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template> 
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the template above, I am able to get what I wanted like below:

```
START HERE
=LDR  00000nam  2200000Ia 4500

=301  \\$abroader$bAbies mariesii$chttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_26321
=302  \\$anarrower$bPinaceae$chttp://aims.fao.org/aos/agrovoc/c_5886
```

However, when I add the following below in the "when template" above, after 'when test=skos:narrower' template:

```
  <xsl:template match="skos:Concept"> 
   <xsl:for-each select="skos:prefLabel">
   <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="following-sibling::skos:closeMatch">
   <xsl:text>=306  \\$aclosematch$b</xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
   <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
```

The problem is I can not integrate the above template which I tested separately from the full template that I've been working on. Am I missing something? Or is my strategy/template correct? Or it might be better if I use another template? Like skos:Concept/skos:prefLabel? or skos:Concept/skos:prefLabel/skos:closeMatch? For reference, the whole xml is here: 128.199.159.143/merged-file.xml. TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my view XSLT code doing `<xsl:for-each select="..."><xsl:choose>...` is usually better written as `<xsl:apply-templates select="..."/>` and then with templates matching elements with predicates, e.g. `<xsl:template match="sko:label[skos:broader]">`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I don't quite see that often in xslt and xpath tutorials. And it seems that's where I'm heading at. I tried this: <xsl:template match="skos:Concept[skos:broader]">
  <xsl:text>=301  \\$abroader</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="skos:prefLabel[@xml:lang='en']" />
    <xsl:text>$c</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="./@rdf:about" />
    <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template> which is based from your comment, I'm getting all prefLabels in various xml:lang attributes that don't have (following)-siblings of either skos:broader, skos:narrower or even skos:closeMatch.